# OBJECT_ID in WHERE clause drops special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using the query below to identify databases for a drop-down list; it works fine, as long as the `DatabaseName` does not have any special characters (such as periods, commas, etc), but of course, we do want to include those.  Now, when I run the `Select` statement by itself, it returns all of the tables correctly, but when I add in the `WHERE` clause, it loses the tables with punctuation in the name. I'm sure that I have a mistake in `OBJECT_ID`, but I just can't figure it out.

```
SELECT [name] AS DatabaseName FROM sys.databases 
WHERE OBJECT_ID ([name] + N'.[dbo].[tblInfo]', N'U') IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY DatabaseName ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QUOTENAME`:

```
WHERE OBJECT_ID (QUOTENAME([name]) + N'.[dbo].[tblInfo]', N'U') IS NOT NULL
```

(Ditto for schema/table names that contain reserved characters)

Comment: I have never seen the QUOTENAME() Function before. That's really useful.  Thanks!

Comment: You should prefer it over just enclosing the name in `[]` as that wont work for a table name that contains `[]` which need the special escaping provided by `QUOTENAME`

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
SELECT [name] AS DatabaseName FROM sys.databases 
WHERE OBJECT_ID (N'[' + [name] + N'].[dbo].[tblInfo]', N'U') IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY DatabaseName ASC
```